# "why don't you" at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, phrases

If a sentence starts with "why don't you" it means suggestion most of the time. Like in "Why don't you put it on a website?".

But what does it mean in this example: "put it on a website, why don'tcha" ?

Comment: It means that person does not know how spell. It also means the same thing.

Comment: I think it's called informal language https://books.google.com/books?id=r6NUluMA198C&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=%22why+dontcha%22+at+the+end+of+a+sentence&source=bl&ots=pyXgXC2zt6&sig=MlY0apm9lI6aQyMctlm85wHsgSo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH_ou9vLTWAhXBxYMKHRm1DmMQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=%22why%20dontcha%22%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20sentence&f=false

Comment: I'm not doubting it's usage. Regardless, it has the same meaning.

Comment: Alex, based on your comment, it looks like you've done some research already but are still confused.  If you edit the question to include the research you've done so far and what you're still confused about, it will help solicit good answers.

Comment: Like almost every statement, It depends on whether it was said sarcastically or not.

Comment: At the end of the sentence makes it sarcastic, like they're saying you shouldn't have put it on the website. It is most likely said AFTER someone did put it on a website.

Comment: I am forgetting the term at the moment, but it's just an interlocutionary particle that makes the request politer. Will post an answer once I remember the correct term.

Answer (score 1):

I believe putting "Why don't you?" or "Why don'tcha?" after a suggestion in US English has one of the following meanings, depending on the context:

1. The suggestion is absurd/comical and the person saying it is expressing frustration through sarcasm at the other person because they have not suggested or undertaken a suitable course of action themsevles. For example:

   > "You're fed up with the lousy food in this prison are you? Write to
   >   the President to complain why don'tcha?"
2. The suggestion is a blindingly obvious thing that should be undertaken immediately and the person saying it is expressing frustration that the other person has not already done it. For example:

   > "The building's on fire! Activate that fire extinguisher you're carrying, why don't you?"

Comment: It's certainly a rare usage in contemporary (2010's) American English. @TimRogers makes a good point about it being used for comical effect. I think it would be something a character in a comedy performance might say, especially if the character were an elderly person from certain immigrant communities.

Answer (score 0):

The first could be considered as either a question: "please tell me the reason why you don't put it on a website", a suggestion framed as a a question "I think you should put it on a website" or somewhere between the two, "I think you should put it on a website, though if you have a good reason not to, please tell me it".

This last has an implication that you're acknowledging that your suggestion might be inappropriate for some reason the person addressed knows better than you, so has an element of humility to the suggestion.

It might be clearly one or the other from context of tone of voice, but I'd probably lean to the last meaning. Tone of voice could even make it very much the opposite of the element of humility I suggest; if you shouted it angrily there'd be more of a sense of "why didn't you do this obvious thing anyone should have thought of?"

The last is clearly making a suggestion, since the suggestion stands as a clause on its own. It's definitely not the first of the three possible readings I mentioned above. It's likely the second, especially as the slurred "why don'tcha?" suggests that the question tagged on the end is [phatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression) rather than actually adding meaning, though it could also be an afterthought moving from the second meaning above to the third; considering only after the suggestion was made that there might be a good reason they already knew for not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Either way the meaning of the text is the same, but the subtext is likely to be interpreted very differently.

Using the word "why" causes many people to feel defensive because it demands an explanation, while an unambiguously direct instruction tends to create emotional resistance. Putting the question in front may make the person defensive but it makes the instruction less direct so there is less emotional resistance. In the first instance one can use tone of voice to either defuse the tension created by the question or drive in the demand for an explanation, making the person feel insulted if there is no good explanation available.

Putting the question at the end makes a direct instruction which challenges the other person's ego. The "why" still creates defensiveness, but because the instruction has already been directly given, it makes the "why" even more of a challenge. Saying it this way tends to suggest that whatever reasons might be offered are irrelevant or that there obviously can't be any reason not to do it that way. It is conceivable that tone of voice could defuse this and make it a constructive suggestion, but it is much more likely to be interpreted as an insult. In the example given, using the contraction in a fairly causual context like a conversation between friends could make it seem more like a casual afterthought which might help defuse the situation. In a more formal context like a business discussion, the contraction could be interpreted as talking down to the other person instead and make it more insulting. In any context, a degree of derision in the tone of voice used while pronouncing the contraction will make the contraction sound more like talking down to the other person.

By constrast, if one said instead "what if you put it on a website?" the meaning of the text is basically the same, but the subtext is much more open and less likely to sound insulting because the question is less of a demand for an explanation.